# C++ Help can't get it work

Tags: c++

Write a program that generates all the factors of a number entered by the user. For instance, the number 12 has the factors 2 * 2 * 3. This program has the following requirements:

1. The user must enter a positive integer. If the user enters something else, your program should output an error message and let the user enter a new value. Use a do/while loop to make sure the user input is successful.
2. The factors must be output in increasing order. The lowest factor your program should report is 2.
3. Your program should output 4 factors per line, each factor in a field of 10 characters. (Hint: the number of factors output determines when to output endl!)
4. You will need a while loop to report the factors. Here are some helpful hints:

   1. If (a % b == 0) then a is a factor of b.
   2. When you have found a factor, output the factor and then reduce the number you are working with by dividing the number by the factor… ie) b = b / a;

**I have this code I can't get it to display the factors. After you enter the number it just ends with out displaying the factors.**

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int factor(int& n)
{
  for(int k=2; k<=n; k++)
    if(n%k==0)
    {
      n = n/k;
      return k;
    }
}


int main()
{
  int n;
  int p=0;

  do
  {
    cout << "Enter a Positive Integer :";
    cin >> n;
  } while(n<=0);

  cout << "Factors are " << endl;

  while(1)
  {
    if(n==1) break;
    cout << factor(n) << " ";
    p++;
    if(p%4==0) 
      cout << endl;   // new line after every 4 factors !!

    system("pause");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: is it a homework? tag it homework then.

Comment: I hope your code is indented better than that!

Comment: Could you also properly indent your code ? It's tough to read like this.

Comment: I assume the requirement is actually for all the prime factors. After all, 4 and 6 are also factors of 12.

Comment: @ted: if you print the smallest factor >= 2 then it's necessarely a prime number (hint: if `m*n` is a factor with both `m` and `n` bigger than 1 then also both of them are factors and are smaller)

Comment: “If (a % b == 0) then a is a factor of b.” This is exactly the contrary: b is a factor of a.

Comment: @6502 - That's why I assumed that the requirement is for all prime factors, even though the spec says, "all factors." Without the hints about how to implement the solution, there's nothing to indicate that 4, 6, and 12 shouldn't be present in the output. In view of this, together with the comment by Benoit, I'd give the instructor a B- for this assignment.

Comment: @ted: sorry, I misunderstood your comment. However not even "all the prime factors" would be correct, as s/he's also asking for the multiplicity (2 is repeated). The problem is about finding the factorization, not just the prime factors...

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult to see due to your (lack of) indentation, but this part :

```
system("pause");
return 0;
```

is **inside** the `while(1)` loop. It should be outside of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

So after indentation it is clear that :

```
 while(1)
 {
  if(n==1) break;
  cout << factor(n) << " ";
  p++;
  if(p%4==0) 
    cout << endl;   // new line after every 4 factors !!

  system("pause");
  return 0;
 }
```

After just calculating and printing the first factor you return from main. So please indent the code and keep proper formatting. Also even if you have single line under `if` , `for` etc, enclose them in braces.